# Color issues with zsh in wsl

Tags: powershell, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm trying to setup oh-my-zsh inside a wsl terminal (using powershell as the console here, but I get the same issue in cmd).  I think I setup all my colors correctly:
[image]

And when I run this:

`print -P '%B%F{red}co%F{green}lo%F{blue}rs%f%b'`

I get the expected:
[image]

But, my prompt is still wrong, as you can tell.  I'm using the agnoster theme and the grey background on the pwd there should be blue.

Is there any way to see the escape sequences so I can determine if the problem is with the escape sequence vs the rendering thereof?

Comment: why don't you use native wsl console?

Comment: There is no native wsl console.  By default, it runs in the cmd console, but that has the same problem for me.

Comment: You might want to check out Joel Bennett's [Pansies](https://github.com/PoshCode/Pansies)

Answer (score 2):

We could examine the [`$PROMPT`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-PROMPT) (or [`$PS1`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-PS1)).

Indeed, oh-my-zsh's agnoster theme [uses `PROMPT_SUBST`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST_002c-use-of) for it. So, we can get the raw escape sequences with redirecting or piping the output of [`print -P`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print):

```
$ print $PROMPT
%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)
$ print -P $PROMPT | cat -v ;# or redirect to a file as you like
^[[39m^[[0m^[[49m^[[40m^[[39m me@mycomputer ^[[44m^[[30mM-nM-^BM-0^[[30m ~ ^[[49m^[[34mM-nM-^BM-0^[[39m
```

These raw escape sequences; the ANSI escape codes, are well described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors. It is the CSI codes `CSI n m` SGR - Select Graphic Renditoin.

Try to describe the above output:

(`^[[39m`: The first two characters are escaped by `cat -v`. We've got `ESC[39m`.)

- `^[[39m^[[0m^[[49m`: which are from `%{%f%k%b%}` part of the `print $PROMPT` output. `^[[39m` to reset default foreground color, `^[[0m` reset every effect and `[[49m` to reset default background color.
- `^[[40m^[[39m me@mycomputer`: bg black and fg default color
- `^[[44m^[[30m M-nM-^BM-0`: bg blue and fg default color (`M-nM-^BM-0` is `cat -v` escaped form of )

At this point, it seems that the prompt outputs a bg blue code for pwd. You could check with
`print -P '%b%F{red}co%F{green}lo%F{blue}rs%f%b'` (Note: the first '%b')

This means the powershell's color pallet setting does not match with the ANSI escape sequences'. We could check whether the terminal's color pallet setting is correct or not with [`16colors.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joejulian/xterm/master/vttests/16colors.sh) in `xterm` distribution if we have `sh` with seeing the output of `sh ./16colors.sh`.
(An example xterm default setting's output could be found for example: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/xterm/16-table.html)

It seems that your powershell's Solarized(?) theme maps the ansi color sequence blue (`^[[44m` or `^[[34m`) as `grey`-ish color for our eyes.

Comment: Don't suppose you can point me at where to get the meaning of this:
`^[[39m^[[0m^[[49m^[[40m^[[39m me@mycomputer ^[[44m^[[30mM-nM-^BM-0^[[30m ~ ^[[49m^[[34mM-nM-^BM-0^[[39m`

Comment: Updated; I've added to try to describe them.